# Smart UV project unmapping outside of UV space

Tags: texturing, uv

I am unwrapping a mesh using the Smart UV Project unwrapper. When I unwrap my mesh some of the UVs are outside of the UV grid. This is undesirable for the following reasons:

- tileable textures will look wrong
- I cannot texture paint the areas outside of the region

I really like how the Smart UV Project method works other than that. __How can I have the Smart UV Project method only unwrap inside of the UV grid?

[image]

**[blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/27089)**

Comment: There is an option in the header > UVs menu to constrain the UVs to the grid, however this only affects transforms. Other than that, all I can think of is writing a python script to fit UVs to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this with smart unwrap it to pack the islands after the are created. CTRL P

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to unwrap using the Smart UV Project method with the constraint that everything must be inside of the UV grid. You will have to fit them in the UV grid after creating them either manually or through a python script.